# Cake Balls with Callebaut chocolate

Tags: chocolate

I have an order for 850 cake balls. In the past I have used chocolate candy melt from the Bulk store.  However I was offered a great deal on Callebaut chocolate wafers so I bought them.  Please tell me that this chocolate will work on Cake Balls.  Specifically dipping and hardening.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you need the chocolate to do with your cake balls?

Answer (score 3):

Notwithstanding my comment (never heard of "Callabraut", I hope it's just a misspelling and not some knock-off brand), if what you've bought is actually Callebaut wafers, then it's couverture and therefore already tempered, and works perfectly well as a shell. I've used Callebaut/Cacao Barry, Valrhona, Felchlin, and others, and they all form solid and much tastier coatings than the compound/coating/"candy" chocolate, provided that they are handled correctly (not overheated, seed wafers added, etc.)

Couverture contains about 35% cocoa butter whereas compound chocolate uses vegetable oil; that's why compound chocolate is cheaper and also slightly more heat-resistant in untempered form. Tempered couverture (which is almost all couverture) will actually come out firmer and shinier than compound chocolate.